# moment createdAt with mongoDB

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, mongodb, ejs

[image]

why my moment keep update every second ?

here's my server.js code:

```
const express = require("express");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const moment = require("moment");

const app = express();

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/messageDashboard', {
    useNewUrlParser: true
});

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    comment: String,
})

const MessageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    message: String,
    comments: [CommentSchema]
})
```

and here's my ejs template:

```
<div id="message-info" class="bg-light">
    <% messages.forEach(message=>{ %>
    <h4>Name: <%= message.name %></h4>
    <h6>
        Message: <%= message.message %>
        <span class="float-right">
            <%= moment(message.createdAt).fromNow() %>
        </span>
    </h6>
```

Comment: I did not seen `createdAt` attribute in your `MessageSchema`.

Comment: is it default in mongoDB? Do we have to create createdAt?

Comment: You have to enable the feature, in default the feature is disabled. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#timestamps . `var thingSchema = new Schema({..}, { timestamps: true });`

Comment: Thanks alot Hoang! Solved it. Appreciate your help! and btw im from vietnam as well xD